# Linux check if file exists Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have tried everything, but I can't seem to check if a directory exists on my system. Here is my code

```
ws("${env.WORKSPACE}") {
 def test = fileExists '/proj'
                sh("ls")
                sh("echo ${test}")
                if(test) {
                sh("echo test")
                }
                else {
//this gets hit
                sh("echo not test")
                }

}
```

this and so many combinations didn't work.

When I ran the ls command the proj directory is there I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: When you do `ls` in what directory? In `/`?

Comment: `fileExists '/proj'` will work successfully as desired. Something else is likely causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

is `/proj` the folder you are looking for or are you looking to check if the directory inside the current workspace exists? In that case it would be `./proj`

you could also do a check with bash

```
def test = sh script: '[ -d "/proj" ]', returnStatus: true
if (test == 0) {
  println 'exist'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - this works for me

```
    stage("test") {
        sh 'mkdir proj'
        sh 'ls'
        if (fileExists('./proj')) {
            sh 'echo found'
        }
        else {
            sh 'echo Notfound'
        } 
    }
```

Output -

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
20:53:45  + mkdir proj
[Pipeline] sh
20:53:45  + ls
20:53:45  proj
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] sh
20:53:45  + echo found
20:53:45  found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```